# Saving processed POST data in a file using PHP

Tags: php, html, file, post

I am working on a chrome extension which sends some HTML stuff to a backend PHP server file. The HTML is sent and received using POST. I am saving the received text(HTML) into a file which stores the stuff as:

```
       "<a href=""http://www.google.com/"">
           <img src=""http://www.google.com/logos/Logo_25wht.gif"" border=""0""  alt=""Google"" align=""middle""></a>"
```

I need the text(HTML) to be saved as:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos /Logo_25wht.gif" border="0" alt="Google" align="middle"></a>
```

Note, I need these things:
    1. Text should come in a single line.
    2. Remove the repeated double quotes(" ") from tag attributes.

My PHP Server page is like this:

```
  if (isset($_POST['content']))
  {

    $url = trim($_POST['content']);

    //$url = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'', $url);
    //$url=str_replace("&ampquot;", "'", $url);
    //$url = str_replace('""', '"', $url);

    $file = fopen("ad_file.csv","a");
    fwrite($file, $url)
    fclose($file); 


   }
?>
```

I also tried the commented options, but no success.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Shakoor Ab, to store anything as a single line, you should use str_replace() and remove \n and \r characters. Regarding the double quotes, you can do the same, but sincerely, I would look at the page side first and find out whythat is being sent. What control is being used to enter this info? TextArea, any kind of editor?

Comment: I am receiving this information from a chrome extension and I need it to store in a file as discussed above.

Comment: @Charle , I already tried them, as in comments. But no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is this:

```
$content = '"<a href=""http://www.google.com/"">
        <img src=""http://www.google.com/logos/Logo_25wht.gif"" border=""0""  alt=""Google"" align=""middle""></a>"';

echo processText($content);

function processText($text)
{
   $text = trim($text, '"');
   $text = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $text);
   $text = str_replace('""', '"', $text);
   $text = preg_replace('#\s{2,}#ims', ' ', $text);
   $text = str_replace('> <', '><', $text);

   return $text;
}
```

It should echo this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/Logo_25wht.gif" border="0" alt="Google" align="middle"></a>
```

Run it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14c0852bb945f70debad32d8cd5305ee650a3f59

Answer (score 0):

There is a `;` missing at :

`fwrite($file, $url)`